# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

[image: Выдает ошибку в первой строке]

Python IDLE, выдаёт ошибку в первой строке. Не могу понять, что не так. Я не понимаю, что сделать. Из-за этого у меня не запускается "программа".

Comment: Разве это Python IDLE? На скриншоте я вижу онлайн-интерпретатор. И в этом интерпретаторе не установлен пакет `tkinter`. И вы вряд ли сможете установить его

Comment: Python IDLE — это интегрированная среда разработки, которая поставляется вместе с интерпретатором (если вы не отказались от неё на этапе установки). Она сама написана на `tkinter`, и в ней этот пакет точно есть

Comment: К тому же `tkinter` — это графическая библиотека. Что вы ожидаете, пытаясь использовать её в браузере? Где должно открыться окно?

Comment: Скачайте Python на python.org. При установке убедитесь, что будет IDLE. И запустите код уже в IDLE

Comment: И, пожалуйста, не публикуйте в дальнейшем код в виде скриншота. Вставьте его текстом. Это очень сильно упростит жизнь отвечающим

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь создать приложение с графическим интерфейсом в браузере (онлайн интерпретаторе).
Просто представьте виртуальная машина которая там стоит должна и запускать, и транслировать вам окно, и обрабатывать события(стоит учитывать что вы не один таким сайтом пользуетесь). На таких сайтах это не поддерживается, нужно скачать python и
если требуется настоящий ide (PyCharm, VisualStudio) и тогда библиотека заработает. Хотя ide не нужно для работоспособности библиотек.
Ссылка на Python: https://www.python.org/
Ссылка на PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: Здесь вы видимо используете сокращение IDLE в значении IDE (интегрированная среда разработки).

Comment: Понял и впрямь, забыл что такая программа в пакете с питоном идет. Уже исправил!